# Leer un fichero desde otra función me da segmentation fault

Tags: c, archivo, punteros

Tengo este pequeño programa y me está volviendo loco. Este es mi main (sigue pero no es importante)

```
main(){
 FILE ** fichero;
 char * aux;
 openFile(fichero);
```

Cuando llamo a esta función me da el error

```
void openFile(FILE **fptr){
 FILE * fichero;
 if ((fichero = fopen("concurrentSum.go", "r")) == NULL){
    printf("Error! opening file");
    exit(1);         
}
 *fptr=fichero; //Donde tengo el seg fault
```

Deberia reservar memoria? si es así donde? No entiendo donde está el problema. Muchas gracias

Comment: Estas en el sitio en español de SO por lo que debes traducir tu pregunta o publicarlo en el sitio en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema radica aquí:

```
FILE ** fichero;
char * aux;
openFile(fichero);
```

Lo que le estás pasando al parámetro `fptr` es basura, es decir, `fptr` debería recibir la dirección de memoria del puntero `fichero`, de ese modo, la función podrá modificar el contenido del puntero que pasaste como referencia.

Ahora, cuando la función `openFile` se ejecute y llegue a esta sentencia:

```
*fptr=fichero;
```

Es donde provocará un fallo de segmentación.

**¿Por qué sucede esto?**

Como el puntero `fptr` no apunta a una dirección de memoria perteneciente al programa, estarías accediendo a una dirección que la aplicación no tiene acceso.

La solución sería declarar la variable `fichero` como un puntero simple (con un nivel de direccionamiento indirecto, es decir, no apuntará a un puntero, sino a un dato).

```
FILE * fichero; //Un puntero simple.
char * aux;
openFile(&fichero); //Le pasamos la dirección de memoria del puntero.
```

Entonces cuando la función `openFile` se ejecute y llegue a esta sentencia:

```
*fptr = fichero;
```

No ocurrirá ningún error de ejecución, porqué nos aseguramos que `fptr` si apunta a una dirección de memoria que le pertenece al programa.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación